# Moving database files created by SQL Server 2012 Express to SQL Standard 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012-express

I am planing to built database driven website with DotNetNuke and SQL Server Express 2012 on my laptop and than host it on web server that has SQL Server 2008 Standard edition.

Is SQL Server 2008 compatible with database files created by Server 2012?

Because I can install and build website using SQL Server 2008 Express Edition and upload to hosting provider server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is SQL Server 2008 compatible with database files created by Server
>   2012?*

**NO.**

SQL Server database files are ***never*** backwards compatible - if you create a database on SQL Server 2012 - there is no way, no hack, no trick, no method to get this to be able to be restored or attached on an earlier version (e.g. 2008 / 2008 R2) of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

No and  it doesn't make much sense if you think about it. If it was the other way around, "maybe" it could be done (I actually never tried) because 2012 would somehow be aware of 2008 structure, but 2008 engine isn't aware of 2012 DB structure.